# Multivariable calculus, taking derivative of composite functions! Help please

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, chain-rule

So I am given the following: 
$$f(x,y)=x^y$$
$$u(x,y) = x + \ln y$$ 
$$v(x,y) = x - \ln y$$ 
and suppose that a new function defined as: $$g(u,v)=f(x(u,v),y(u,v))$$
and I am asked to find the partial derivative at a two points one of which is $\partial g(3,3)/\partial u$.

I am more interested in the way of thinking and approaching the question rather than the solution. 
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Is $x(u,v)$ the solution of $x$ satisfying $x+lny=u$ and $x-lny=v$ given $u$ and $v$?

Comment: This was all the information i am given! i suspect by $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$ the author means the partial derivative of $(u,v)$ with respect to $x$, and $y$ respectively

Comment: So does $x(u,v)$ mean $\large{{\partial u \over\partial x}+{\partial v \over\partial x}}$ which is basically $2$?

Comment: You can derive a formula for $x$ in terms of $u + v$ (which gives you a simple way to write $x(u,v)$) and a formula for $y$ in terms of $u - v$ (which gives you a simple way to write $y(u,v)$), so maybe that's the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Assuming $x(u,v)$ means the solution of $x$ satisfying $x+lny=u$ amd $x-lny=v$, we have $x(u,v)=\large{u+v\over2}$ and $y(u,v)=\large{e^{u-v\over2}}$.

Now $g=\large{({u+v\over2})^{e^{u-v\over2}}}$.

$\large{{\partial g\over\partial u}=({u+v\over2})^{e^{u-v\over2}}\cdot({\partial (e^{u-v\over2}ln({u+v\over2}))\over\partial u})}$

$\large{{\partial g\over\partial u}=({u+v\over2})^{e^{u-v\over2}}\cdot({{1\over2}e^{u-v\over2}ln({u+v\over2})}+{1\over u+v}e^{u-v\over2})}$.

(2) Assuming $x(u,v)$ means $\large{{\partial u \over\partial x}+{\partial v \over\partial x}}$

Then $x(u,v)=2$ and $y(u,v)=0$ and $g=2^0=1$ and $\large{{\partial g\over\partial u}}=0$